# Can you use a semicolon to separate a question?

Tags: questions, semicolons

e.g., 
"I'm ordering five guys; do you want some?

Comment: Yes. It binds the contextual statement to the question part quite nicely, and variations on it are very common in writing. In speech it's not an issue, because a semicolon is just a full stop intonation. We can't tell the difference when talking, and still manage to understand, so it can't be important.

Comment: People often use semicolons when the sections they are separating have themselves commas in them.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. There's no grammar rule that requires/limits specific punctuation at the end of a sentence with a semicolon in it.